# Launching Sinatra at Terminal stays blank

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I was trying to run Sinatra and Ruby in my MacBook, and all was working fine. Then, suddenly, I tried again and it just stays like this:

[image: This is how my terminal looks like after I enter that command]

I can't access to localhost or anything. I don't know what to do. I've been researching for hours. Please, help me.

This is what my ruby code looks like:

```
require 'sinatra'
gets '/ejemplo1' do
    puts 'Hello World'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a typo. Should be **get** and not **gets**.

```
require 'sinatra'
get '/ejemplo1' do
    puts 'Hello World'
end
```

Additional info:

**gets** in ruby is a way to get user input:

```
name = gets
puts "Your name is #{name}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned by @Norly Canarias you should use `get` for routing in sinatra. Moreover if you use `puts` statement in `get` block it will print only in terminal when you run your code not in webpage when you access localhost. Correct way to make it display in webpage is given below

```
require 'sinatra'
get '/ejemplo1' do 
    'Hello World' 
end
```